# ssh: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, digital-ocean

One colleague has worked on a server, and written `ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and the password in our documentation.

I just did `ssh-keygen` on my machine, and tried to do `ssh -v root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` from my machine, but I got the following error.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Pw4cFx5c2WGJzTwTL+gsx3AMHMEuT0sei1fz5oGCrac
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/softtimur/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:EL7hm5LvdVADZiv662nneDEeoLKy+etj8OT61eugu4Y /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/softtimur/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit 1:**

In my local mac, `curl ipecho.net/plain ; echo` returns `175.169.13.102`. I managed to open a console from the droplet of Digital Ocean of **A**, then I did `ssh-keygen`, then in the console, I did `ssh-copy-id softtimur@175.169.13.102` which returned the follows; password was not asked.

I still cannot believe a server can write files to my local mac as if my local mac was a server...

[image]

Comment: Did you also run the `ssh-copy-id` command?

Comment: No, I did not try `ssh-copy-id`. Actually, I am confused, I don't know which/whose key should be in the server and which/whose key should be in my local...

Comment: Private keys should always remain on the server that generates the key. Private keys should *never* be shared. If you run `ssh-copy-id user@host` replacing the host by the server from whom you want to connect to, you'll connect to the other server and deploy the public key, which is the one that will be used to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a way to deploy the public-key authentication method is the following. Assume you have servers **A** (the server; the one you want to connect to) and **B** (the client; the one from whom you want to connect to **A** using the public key).

1. On **A**, run the following command:

   `ssh-keygen`

   - This will generate a private-public key pair, if run without arguments, it will do so under `~/.ssh`.
2. On **A**, run:

   `ssh-copy-id [user@]<Bs-IP-address>`

   - This will copy the *public* key generated by **A** to **B**. It will do so in a file called `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
   - If this does not work due to connectivity problems or you simply can't connect from point **A** to **B**, there's an alternative (manual) way of doing so. In your machine **A**, go to your `~/.ssh` directory and find your public key file. This will probably be a file with the `.pub` extension. Open it and copy the content, and in **B** append/paste it into your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. **Very important**: This file has to be owned by the user, the group has to be the user's and have permissions `600`. Otherwise *it will not work*. This is pretty much what `ssh-copy-id` does.
3. From **B**, try to connect by SSH to **A**.

A few things to note:

- The command in point 2 will deploy the public key to the remote user you're connecting to only. That means that if you deploy the key to the home of `tom`, a user whose username is `jerry` won't be able to use it. In short, the deployment is per-user.
- If you're trying to deploy the key to connect to **A** with `root`, make sure the `PermitRootLogin` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has either a value of `yes` or `prohibit-password` (preferably). If set to `no`, public method authentication will not work.
- **Never** share a private key with anyone.

Comment: Thank you for this... I just want to clarify that I want to connect to the server (**A** in your answer?) from my local machine (**B** in your answer?), then how could I get `<Bs-IP-address>`?

Comment: Yes, in my case **A** is the server and **B** the client. Usually running `ifconfig` on **B** you'll able to see its IP address.

Comment: 1) Is the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in **A** or **B**? 2) In Step 2, I still cannot believe something can be written to my local machine. What if my machine is turned off when people do `ssh-copy-id` in **A**?

Comment: 1) The authorized keys file should be on **B**. These keys (you can have as many as you want) are the ones that will be used to authenticate using SSH via public-private key authentication. 2) `ssh-copy-id` will use the SSH protocol to deploy the key. That's why the IP address of B is necessary. You'll be prompted to write the password as well, which is normal because **A** is not authorized to connect to **B** using the private-public authentication way. So yes, your machine should be online when deploying the key.

Comment: Please see the update of my OP...

Comment: That seems to be a connectivity problem. Are you forwarding port `22/TCP` to your local machine in your firewall? Has your local machine port `22/TCP` opened for this connection?

Comment: Please see my edit, concretely point 2, I added a manual way to deploy the public key.

Comment: Thank you again... I finally managed to copy the public key of **A** to my local `.ssh/authorized_keys`. The permission of the file is `600, the user is `softtimur` and the group is `staff`, but `ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` returned again `Permission denied (publickey)`. Should I change the group of the file (to what)?

Comment: Please see `Your public key needs to be in the authorized_keys file on your Droplet...` of [this thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/error-permission-denied-publickey-when-i-try-to-ssh), your answer and his answer are quite opposite...

Comment: We're saying exactly the same. In that case I assume he's trying to authenticate from his Droplet to his local computer, while you're trying to do the opposite. The public key needs to be in the `authorized_keys` of the machine that wants to connect to the server, which is pretty much what he's saying. Have you checked whether on the server side you have `PermitRootLogin` to `prohibit-password` or `yes`?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer (and the comments of its author) has some flaws: It mixes up roles of *server* and *client*. <sub><sup>As this answer is (as judged by moderating co-members) diverging too much from the original to be accepted as a mere edit, it is posted here in its entirety:</sup></sub>

A possible way to deploy the public-key authentication method is the following: Assume you have a **SSH server A** (the server that you want to connect to) and the **SSH client B** (the client; the system from which you want to connect to server **A** using public key authentication).

0. Generate a personal public/private pair of keys on **client B**.

   - On **B**, run the following command:

     `ssh-keygen`

     - This will generate a personal private-public key pair on the client **B**, if run without arguments, the keys will be stored in `~/.ssh`.
1. Deploy your *public key* on the **server A**.

   - On **B**, run:

     `ssh-copy-id [<user-on-A>@]<A's-IP-address>`

     - This will copy your *public key* (generated by you on **B** in step 0) to **A**. It will do so in a file on **A** called `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. In order to authenticate to **A** during this process you have to provide other credentials, e.g. a username/password combination. (The server has to allow this login method.)
   - If you can't connect or login to **server A** that way, you can manually transfer your *public key* onto **server A** by whatever means that work for you. On the **client B** you find *public key* in a file probably ending in `.pub` in your `~/.ssh` directory. The content (a line of plain ASCII text) has to be appended to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on **server A**.

     **Very important**: This file has to be owned by the user, the group has to be the user's and have permissions `600`. Otherwise *it will not work*. This is pretty much what `ssh-copy-id` does.
2. From **client B**, try to connect by SSH to **server A**.

A few things to note:

- The fact that you have been able to deploy one of your *public keys* to an account on **server A** (into its `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`file, that is), is enough prove for **server A**, that you will be allowed to login to that account by proving that you know the *secret key* (which stays on **B**) matching the *public key*. To put it simplified: During SSH public key authentication your **client** signs a challenge, the **server** verifies the signature using the *public key*.
- If you're trying to deploy the key to connect to **A** with `root`, make sure the `PermitRootLogin` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has either a value of `yes` or `prohibit-password` (preferably). If set to `no`, public method authentication will not work.
- **Don't** share a *private key* with anyone.